# When new ViewController is activated a passed varieble is first (null) and then correct

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've got a very stupid problem. I have a `TableView` where I'd like to make each cell editable by pushing into a `DetailController`. It's working so far, but when I do

```
NSLog(@"selectedItem: %@", selectedItem_);
```

in `viewDidLoad`, the log displays:

```
selectedItem: (null)
selectedItem: Toe
```

RootViewController (`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`):

```
NSString *selectedItem = [content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
detailViewController.selectedItem_ = selectedItem;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

DetailViewController (`viewDidLoad`):

```
NSLog(@"selectedItem: %@", selectedItem_);
[super viewDidLoad];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot assume that viewDidLoad is called only once. it may be called multiple times if the view is unloaded because of memory, or when the view is getting loaded from the nib.

put the initialization in your init method.

similar question and answer on stackoverflow

[viewDidLoad getting called twice on rootViewController at launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081131/viewdidload-getting-called-twice-on-rootviewcontroller-at-launch)