# using 2 NSTimer in the same UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, nstimer

In my `viewDidLoad` method I have the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self repeatRequest];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target: self selector: @selector(repeatRequest) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

And here are the methods that get called:

```
- (void) repeatRequest{
    NSLog(@"backgroundRequest");
  }

- (void) onTimer{
    NSLog(@"flip pages");
}
```

The thing is the everything works well for a 2 minutes and the methods get called as setted...but after that everything goes astray and `onTimer` method gets called every second an not one time at five seconds.And also the `repeatrequest` is called more often that it should be.Anyone knows which may be the cause?

Comment: i think problem in your another code of this view, because i check it for 1 hr it work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given us too much information to work with, but I would guess that for whatever reason your `viewDidLoad` method is being called multiple times which results in many duplicate timers which keep calling your `repeatRequest` and `onTimer` methods.

You probably want to take a look at why `viewDidLoad` might be being called multiple times. Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081131/viewdidload-getting-called-twice-on-rootviewcontroller-at-launch). You should assume that `viewDidLoad` is allowed to be called more than once.

(To check this, just add `NSLog(@"viewdidload");` into your `viewDidLoad` method and seeing how often that gets called.)

What you should really be doing, therefore, is storing your `NSTimer` instances as ivars (assume they are called `timer1` and `timer2` respectively), then checking whether they exist already when `viewDidLoad` is called:

```
if (!timer1) timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target: self selector: @selector(repeatRequest) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
if (!timer2) timer2 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be creating multiple instances of those timers, perhaps because your view is actually loaded multiple times. You might out a log or breakpoint when the timers are created to verify that.

You should keep a reference to the timers that you create in viewDidLoad so that you can properly invalidate them in viewDidUnload.

Comment: [timer invalidate]; (you need to keep a reference to the timer in an ivar or property)