# View Controller Loads Twice - How Do I Fix It?

Tags: ios, xml, xcode

**The Problem Cause**

When I added a new Swift class file to my iOS project, I decided I was indecisive and renamed it, deleted it, and created a new file. I think that I was actually so indecisive that I renamed it a few times.

**The Problem**

Now that viewController loads twice. I can literally see the transition happen twice and, during testing, I can see my viewDidLoad run twice in my console.

**Common Fix**

I know the first solution to check for is duplicate segues / segue calls. Check your document outline to see if there's more than one segue. In my case, it is definitely not a segue problem in the storyboard or the viewController.

**My Uncommon Situation**

I found someone who had the same load-twice problem and it was because of the rename:

[image: Screenshot]

They said it was the renaming I did that is at the root of my problem and it is not easy to fix because the duplication is now in my XML file. But where is this XML file and how do I edit it to erase the original instance of the class? I have no idea.

So how do I solve this loads-twice issue? I just want my viewController to have a normal segue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved my issue!

If you messed around with a class's name (or it's file name) and have the same "loads twice" issue that I was having, you might be having a hard time solving it. The only suggested solutions I found said to create a new project from scratch and copy stuff over. BUT, instead...

**Here's the simplest solution ever:**

Rename the class of the viewController that's loading twice! Don't worry about the file, but the view controller class within it. Your XML file probably has duplicates of the original class name, but rename your class to something entirely new and you should be okay.

Answer (score 3):

## Delete Segue and declare it the right way.

I faced the same problem. The reason was I ctrl dragged from the TableViewCell to target ViewController.
So I deleted the segue simply by clicking on it and pressing the delete key on my keyboard.
Then ctrl dragged from the ViewContoller of the first view to the second ViewController.

> ### The wrong way to declare Segue

[image]

> ### The Right way to declare Segue
>
> [image]

Comment: There is no wrong or right. It just more obvious if done the second way. That was exactly what cause issue in my case. I have segue implemented manually (#2 option), but then deleted segue representation from my Main.storyboard and reimplemented it using option #1 - which made Xcode thinking I have double segues for each connection hence View Controllers were loading twice.

Comment: @marika.daboja thanks for your input and adding more value to this answer.

Comment: Thanks dude, this saved me a lot of annoyance!

Comment: Thanks.  Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me also. My case was for Creating a **segue** from my **UIButton** and performing it from source code.
If it matches to your case then just create the segue direct from the **ViewController** to your desired ViewController.
The perform the segue. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created the same problem where my view was loading twice. I have a tabbed app. The view controllers for each tab uses a Content View with a segue. For some reason I had set the Custom Class for the View Controller and the Content View Controller to the same custom class.

[image: View Controllers]

I don't know how both got set, probably something I did and forgot. If you are seeing a view controller load twice and the above answers didn't help, check to see if you have the parent view and the content view using the same custom class.