# Pushing View Controller Twice

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Within my app I'm having an issue with the following error:

```
Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported
```

It's a bug report that's comeback from a few users. We've tried to replicate it but can't (double tapping buttons etc). This is the line we use to open the view controller:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let editView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EditViewController") as! EditViewController
editView.passedImage = image
editView.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
if !(self.navigationController!.topViewController! is EditViewController) {
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editView, animated: true)
}
```

Anybody have any ideas? I've done a bit of research and most answers on Stack we've covered so are at a bit of a loss for how to investigate.

Comment: How would you recommend Dershowitz123?

Comment: Try `if !(self.navigationController!.topViewController! is EditViewController.self)` .

Answer (score 9):

Try this to avoid pushing the same VC twice:

```
if !(self.navigationController!.viewControllers.contains(editView)){
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editView, animated:true)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the pushViewController is asynchronous since iOS7, if you tap the button that push view controller too fast, it will be pushed twice.
I have met such issue, the only way I tried is to set a flag when push is invoked (i.e `- navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`) and unset the flag when the delegate of UINavigationController is called `- navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`

It's ugly, but it can avoid the twice-push issue.

Comment: Why did apple make it asynchronous?

Answer (score 3):

In the function that does the push:

`guard navigationController?.topViewController == self else { return }`

Comment: It's a really good solution, but doesn't work 100% times. For example, when segue is in progress.

Answer (score 2):

The completion block of `CATransaction` to the rescue :)

The animation of `pushViewController(:animated:)` is actually pushed onto the `CATransaction` stack, which is created by each iteration of the `run loop`. So the completion block of the `CATransaction` will be called once the `push` animation is finished.

We use a boolean variable `isPushing` to make sure new view controller can't be pushed while already pushing one.

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    var isPushing = false

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if !isPushing {
            isPushing = true
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                self.isPushing = false
            }
            super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but it's not always blocking. It works in all places in my app except one: I have PageViewController and from controller inside it I'm calling pushViewController. It's calling the overridden function, but still sometimes is called second time after first push is done. I had to add another blockade in this particular class.